# Write PHP variables into apache log

Tags: php, apache, logging

Is there a way to write PHP variables (and arrays) into apache log? To have some server-side debugging ablility directly?

Comment: It is possible under some circumstances. But please consider this solution as dirty. A PHP-Application should use it's own logging-functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [error_log](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-log.php) function. It will log to the web server error log regarding the its settings. It will work in any case - apache, nginx, php-cgi, php-fpm

To write variables you can use

```
error_log('MyObject is '.var_export($my_object, true));
```